# Why is Java telling me "" is a valid date?

Tags: java, datetime

So, this is what I'm using as my `isDate` in Java.

```
public class Common {
    public static final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    public static boolean isDate(String text) {
        return isDate(text, DATE_PATTERN);
    }

    public static boolean isDate(String text, String date_pattern) {
        String newDate = text.replace("T00:00:00", "");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(date_pattern);
        ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
        formatter.parse(newDate, position);
        formatter.setLenient(false);
        if (position.getIndex() != newDate.length()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my test code:

```
String fromDate = "";

if (Common.isDate(fromDate)) {
    System.out.println("WHAT??????");
}
```

I see `WHAT??????` printed every time.  What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Try testing with `position.getErrorIndex() != -1`. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/ParsePosition.html#getErrorIndex%28%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to check for a successful parse is to see, if the `parse` method returns a Date or `null`. Try this:

```
public static boolean isDate(String text, String date_pattern) {
    String newDate = text.replace("T00:00:00", "");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(date_pattern);
    ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
    formatter.setLenient(false);
    return formatter.parse(newDate, position) != null;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will also return true for dates such as "2003-03-01sdfsdf" ( assuming you're not doing the replace in the first line )

Comment: Good point.  Currently this is used in one place that accepts only one kind of date (which is why I remove the "T00...")  Is there a more bullet proof method?

Answer (score 6):

It is because your logic is not correct. `newDate=""`, i.e. `newDate.length()==0`. As well as `position.getIndex()==0` since the error is occuring at the very beginning of the string. You may test whether `position.getErrorIndex()>=0`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel... use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) ;)

```
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime("blub235asde");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "blub235asde"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:673)
    at Test.main(Test.java:21)
```